# Problems With Linking JavaScript with Html

Tags: javascript, html, css

Here is my html linking the .js file

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="CSS/Style.css">
        <title>
            Learning JavaScript
        </title>
    </head>

    <body>
    <div class="LargeTitle">
        <h1>Learning JavaScript</h1>
        <p class="UnderText">asap</p>
    </div>
    </body>
<script scr="Scripts/MainJavaScript.js"></script>
</html>
```

and here is a picture of the file locations
File Location = https://i.stack.imgur.com/q1mGq.jpg

and here is the script:
alert("Is it working?");

Hopefully someone can help me with this

Comment: Help you with what?  What's the problem?  What do your developer tools tell you?  Start by moving your script tag inside `<head>` or `<body>`.  Learn to use an HTML validator.  https://validator.w3.org/  Turn on file name extensions in your file explorer so you can see what's going on.

Answer (score 4):

You have a typo, change `<script scr="Scripts/MainJavaScript.js"></script>` to `<script src="Scripts/MainJavaScript.js"></script>`

The attribute for script should be `src` instead of `scr`

Also, put the script tag inside the `body` tag or the `head` tag

Comment: Good catch Joe.